# Samsung Note 2 does not assign received IP

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-note-2, dhcp

I am trying to connect a Samsung Note II ( OS: Android 4.0, Ice cream Sandwich) through Wi-Fi to a DHCP Server. The DHCP server(192.168.3.29) is running on a Virtual Machine with OS as Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit. A D-link Wi-Fi access point is connected to this DHCP server. The DHCP server sends the IP(192.168.3.100) to the Samsung Note II but the device fails to assign the IP address. The samsung device never had any problem connecting with other DHCP servers. Please let me know if you need any other details.

I've checked it with Wireshark, which shows that the DHCP server accepts the request from the device:

[image: Wireshark Screenshot]
<sup>Wireshark screenshot -- click it to see it in full resolution</sup>

<sup>Question was closed as off-topic on SO, and I was redirected here -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962600/samsung-note-2-does-not-assign-received-ip</sup>

Comment: Not a solution, but a work-around until there is one: Long-tap the AP in your WiFi settings, check "Advanced". Then you can manually assign the device an IP address etc. (e.g. the same the DHCP server assigned either). This even allows you to specify your own name server, which can be quite useful (I have no idea why Android does not take *that* from the DHCP offer, but always uses its pre-configured servers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. It was because of huge network traffic on the DHCP server, due to which the ACK was not able to reach through Wi-Fi to the Samsung Galaxy Android.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem after an upgrade. After a LOT of digging I found the problem. Before starting, note that your device must be rooted to fix it.

Believe or not, the problem is with the "ls" command in /system/bin. It looks like a lot of the commands are symbolic links to a file called "toolbox", which is also located in the "/system/bin" directory. The "ls" command however links to what I think was the previous location "/data/local/toolbox".

Fix is: Using a suitable file manager (I used Root Explorer), copy toolbox from /system/bin to /data/local.

I guess you could also try update the ls symbolic link to point to /system/bin/toolbox, but I'm not sure how to do this AND there may be other link with the same problem.

Device : Samsung Galaxy Tab GT-P7510
New Android Version : ICS 4.0.4
Old Android Version : HC 3.2